# Payable function that should not accept the money if X but still write changes

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.6.x

I have a function that is payable. Upon some checks, if it meet the condition, it should write some changes BUT refund the payable amount that was just sent.

See:

```
function rent(uint256 tokenId, uint256 period, address payable owner) onlyOffPause() payable public returns (bool) {


require(period > minMonthBasic && period <= maxMonthBasic);

require(owner == ownerOf(tokenId));




//this allow owner to change renting price so it can be used when due date care.

//if marked as rented, require the sender to be the actual renter. this allow renew priority under 31 grace before evict. If not rented, accept anyone to start a rent.
if(plotdata[tokenId]._rented){
    require(msg.sender == renterOf(tokenId));

    //require the basic care date to be due, this giving a 31 days grace for any owner or even renter

    require(checkBasicCare(tokenId) == true);

    //if rentingPrice 0, removing renter and refunding them for the period left AND CANCEL THIS FUNCTION

    if(plotdata[tokenId]._lastRentingPrice == 0){
        plotdata[tokenId]._rented = false;

        plotdata[tokenId]._renterOf = address(0);

        // !!! IT SHOULD NOT ACCEPT THE MONEY AT THIS POINT BUT STILL KEEP THE PREVIOUS CHANGE AT THE RENTER OF AND RENTED

    }

}

...
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question? You can simply do `msg.sender.transfer(msg.value)` if that's what you're asking (didn't see a single question mark in this post).

Comment: Oh much appreciated. I thought it was better to not assume money would be received in the contract

Comment: @btc4cash It sound like a wrong abstraction to me, isn't it better to create a separate function that doesn't accept payments for that particular case?

Comment: yeah but that would require to base on the fact user may never call it. Best for us at this point is to send back msg.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what exactly is the question? You can simply do msg.sender.transfer(msg.value) if that's what you're asking (didn't see a single question mark in this post). – goodvibration